# What will happen to a neuron if I suddenly remove the pump but not the leaky Na+ and K+ channels?

Tags: electrophysiology

K<sup>+</sup> is more abundant inside the cell and thus has a propensity to move outwards. It has an equilibrium potential of -80 mV. Na<sup>+</sup> is more abundant extracellularly and thus has a propensity to move inwards. It has an equilibrium potential of 58 mV. The resting membrane potential of a cell is about -70 mV. So, K<sup>+</sup> moves out (more towards its equilibrium potential) and Na<sup>+</sup> moves in (more towards its equilibrium potential). The pumps throw out the Na<sup>+</sup> and bring back in K<sup>+</sup> thus maintaining their concentration and hence the membrane potential.

Now if I suddenly remove the pump from the cell, what would happen? Will the cell moves towards K<sup>+</sup>'s equilibrium potential or towards Na<sup>+</sup>'s equilibrium potential? I know that the answer is that the cell will discharge and have a membrane potential of 0 mv, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Na<sup>+</sup> and K<sup>+</sup> will move according to the electrochemical gradient. Given that K<sup>+</sup> leaky channels are ever present, the cell is already around its K<sup>+</sup> equilibrium. If you introduce leaky Na<sup>+</sup> channel and remove the pumps, eventually the cell will be nothing more than a passive membrane and it will adopt the same concentrations of ions as the extracellular space, i.e., Na<sup>+</sup> will pour in along its electrochemical gradient, after which K<sup>+</sup> (formerly already at equilibrium) will start pouring out alongside its chemical gradient, due to the reduced electrical gradient because of Na<sup>+</sup> coming in.

Comment: Why will K+'s electrical gradient reduce due to Na+ coming in? And say, if I remove the pump but do not introduce Na+ leaky channels, then what will happen? Will the K+ still pour out?

Comment: @BlackDagger -  1) inside less negative 2) more slowly - eventually every battery discharges

Comment: Why will it discharge eventually --- I'm asking from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: @BlackDagger stochastics; channels are never fully closed. A cell is not a sealed container. Even batteries discharge spontaneously.

Comment: No I mean, why will the cell discharge? The K+ will pour out but as soon as it reaches the equilibrium potential of K+, it should stop pouring out and reach a steady state. Why will it further discharge and go to 0 mv.

Comment: cause Na+ goes in